# undefined=undefined gets appended to ajax request URL

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, ajax, razor

I have an ajax call in my razor application, which is suppose to call this endpoint

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<JsonResult> OnPostWorkflowStatus(int actionId, int workflowId, int newTemplateId = -1)
```

and the ajax call

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/rebates/api/Workflow/OnPostWorkflowStatus?actionId="+actionId+"&workflowId="+workflowId+"&newTemplateId="+template_id,
        datatype: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function(result) {
            //do something
        },
        error: function(result) {
            showErrorToastWorkflowAction("someErrorMessage");
        }
    });
```

This works in most cases but sometime randomly an error is thrown and the issue URL looks like this on the chrome console

> ...api/Workflow/OnPostWorkflowStatus?actionId=65&workflowId=50&newTemplateId=-1&undefined=undefined

I suspect the issue is caused by the undefined param.
Why is this being added?
Can this be the root cause?

PS: We had some trouble with the F5 system recently due to high loading time, could this be related?

Comment: When the problem occurs, what is the exact observed value of `template_id`?  When the problem occurs, if you capture the value used for the `url` parameter before using it, what is that value?  If this happens infrequently and seemingly randomly then you may need to add some logging for this information and wait for the next time it happens.

Comment: The url I've pasted on the question is from the last attempt. The 3 parameters are as it should be. newTemplateId should be -1 & that works in most usually @David

Comment: *"newTemplateId should be -1 & that works in most usually"* - But if logging this information determines that it **doesn't** work as expected or **isn't** that value then that would give you a direction for your debugging.  What the code **should** do is less relevant than what it **does** do, and the latter is exactly what you need to find out.  The code shown doesn't indicate any reason why this would be happening.  Another possibility is that perhaps there is some custom setup to jQuery's AJAX functionality which is doing this.